# How do I find outdated libraries with sbt?

Tags: sbt

How can I find libraries which have newer versions with sbt.

For Ruby bundler, it can be done with `bundle outdated`. I want to do similar thing with sbt.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There is [sbt-updates](https://github.com/rtimush/sbt-updates) which gives you latest stable and snapshot versions. Not sure how reliable it is, though.

Example run:

```
my-project $ sbt
[info] Set current project to my-project
> dependencyUpdates
[info] Found 14 dependency updates for my-project
[info]   com.typesafe.akka:akka-actor                                  : 2.2.1  -> 2.2.3 
[info]   com.typesafe.akka:akka-agent                                  : 2.2.1  -> 2.2.3 
[info]   com.typesafe.akka:akka-dataflow                               : 2.2.1  -> 2.2.3 
[info]   com.typesafe.akka:akka-slf4j                                  : 2.2.1  -> 2.2.3 
[info]   com.typesafe.akka:akka-testkit                                : 2.2.1  -> 2.2.3 
[info]   com.typesafe.akka:akka-zeromq                                 : 2.2.1  -> 2.2.3 
[info]   org.scala-lang.plugins:continuations:plugin->default(compile) : 2.10.2 -> 2.10.3
[info]   org.scala-lang:scala-library                                  : 2.10.2 -> 2.10.3
[info]   org.scalaz:scalaz-concurrent                                  : 7.0.3  -> 7.0.5 
[info]   org.scalaz:scalaz-core                                        : 7.0.3  -> 7.0.4 
[info]   org.scalaz:scalaz-effect                                      : 7.0.3  -> 7.0.5 
[info]   org.scalaz:scalaz-iteratee                                    : 7.0.3  -> 7.0.5 
[info]   org.scalaz:scalaz-typelevel                                   : 7.0.3  -> 7.0.5 
[info]   org.scalaz:scalaz-xml                                         : 7.0.3  -> 7.0.5
```

Comment: Nifty 1 liner (as of sbt `1.1.1`): `sbt my-project/dependencyUpdates`

Answer (score 2):

You can use "SBT > dependencyUpdates" in the command line. Just like described above. That will work. But that is now automated.

You can use [VersionEye](https://www.versioneye.com) to monitor your build.sbt file on GitHub/Bitbucket. VersionEye will notify you about out-dated dependencies in your project, automatically via email. In that way it is completely automated and you don't have to remember to execute commands in the shell. It's like a CI Server for versions ;-)

By the way, I'm the dude who started VersionEye. Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: ...could have been a comment :)

Comment: In that case I'm sorry :) Next time I know better.